# Video play then onended() overlayed by still image with links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, html5-video

I am very new to HTML5, so I am trying to find the most easy way of playing a premade video from Adobe After Effects in HTML5, then replacing the last frame with a still image that has clickable icons.

1) I have tried a lot of JS,JQuery examples, work great, but I cannot replace the video with something else, since I cannot make them on top of each other.
2) I thought of making this in Adobe Animate CC, or ActionScript for a complete SWF that at the end would be clickable links, but it's too complicated process.

Any ideas regarding JS/JQuery approach?

Update @jms I have implemented your idea:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<script src=
"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
 libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<body>
<script>
document.querySelector('#videoPlayer').addEventListener('progress', 
function(evt) {
if(evt.total-evt.loaded <= 1) {
    evt.target.pause();
    document.querySelector('.over-buttons').classList.add('show-icons');
} 
}</script>


<div class="video-container">
<video id="videoPlayer" controls>
  <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div class="over-buttons">YOUR ELEMENTS THAT WILL BE SHOWED IN THE LAST 
SECOND </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option that you could try, i don't know if it may be enough for you. You can try to put your player inside another element, and attach some events to your player in order to pause it in the last second, and then show the other elements inside your parent element which you should positioning over your video. Something like

```
<div class="video-container">
    <video id="videoPlayer" src="resource_url"></video>
    <div class="over-buttons"><!--YOUR ELEMENTS THAT WILL BE SHOWED IN THE LAST SECOND --></div>
</div>
```

Then, you can attach the event `progress` to the video element, and when it was the last second (compared for instance with the video property `duration` or the `loaded` property of the event), then you can pause the video and add a class that shown the `over-buttons` div

```
document.querySelector('#videoPlayer').addEventListener('progress', function(evt) {
    if(evt.total-evt.loaded <= 1) {
        evt.target.pause();
        document.querySelector('.over-buttons').classList.add('show-icons');
    } 
}
```

---

Edit 1: I have made a little example. I've checked that some navigators doesn't emit properly progress event, so it is better to manually check with an interval current video position. You could check it at jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8mfwv0zc/1/

Comment: Let me give this a spin! Thanks!! Could you turn this into a workable example, since I am very new to JS and HTML5?